# Scrape links from https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to scrape this webpage: https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001, specifically looking to grab the *latest* Article # from the table for Windows Server 2016 (or alternatively, the smaller table, grabbing the corresponding SSU Package number), which today, would be 4465659.

I'm working on a script to automate grabbing this latest Servicing Stack Update, and also the latest Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016. I've got the Cumulative Update section working, but the same approach doesn't yield a result on the above link.

For reference, my Cumulative Update approach is below. It parses the page, performs a few adjustments, and ends up with the KBID that I can feed into a download script, which I know works. The problem with using this against the above link, is that the page content appears to be dynamically populated from elsewhere, so I can't seem to get any actual table content returned in PowerShell, from which I would be able to interrogate further.

Also, I need to -UseBasicParsing as this is executing on a Windows Server, potentially with IE out of the picture.

Thanks!
Matt

```
$buildVersion = "14393"
$kbID = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825' -UseBasicParsing).RawContent -split "`n"
$kbID = ($kbID | Where-Object { $_ -like "*heading*$buildVersion*" } | Select-Object -First 1)
$kbID = ((($kbID -split "KB", 2)[1]) -split "\s", 2)[0]
```

Comment: the last time i read a post about this sort of thing, the solution chosen was to use chrome in dev mode to watch what happened when the page generated the DL link. then try to emulate that in the response sent back to the site. ///// don't ask me HOW ... i just lurked. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with simple http client, because that page runs some javascript and more over it first redirects you to eula page that you need to check/accept. You may google for some rest api returning same data or some other source with static html.

If not - you still can automate it, but you'd need to use actual browser. I guess the most popular way to do it is to use Selenium (it will use FireFox, Chrome or IE). There are probably some other headless browser.

Below is the solution with firefox (install it if not yet), but I believe you can do it with other browsers too. You will also need a C# driver (WebDriver.dll, it's inside Selenium.WebDriver.3.14.0.nupkg) and Mozilla GeckoDriver (geckodriver.exe). You can download it from here: https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Put all files in the same folder with you powershell script. The script below:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\stack\selenium\WebDriver.dll"

$driver = [OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver]::new()

$driver.manage().timeouts().ImplicitWait = [timespan]::FromSeconds(5)

$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001")

$driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".ng-untouched").Click()  # check eula box 

$driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".btn-primary").Click()   # click accept button

#select rows of the seconds table
$data = $driver.FindElementsByTagName("table")[1].FindElementsByTagName("tr").text

$driver.quit()

$data | Select-String "Windows Server 2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without invoking IE or using some other UI automation.
If you have not hit the page before you get prompted to accept the first page.

Once you hit this URL: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825

.. you'll find yourself here:

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001

Once there the main source of this page does not directly contain the table, if you inspect the table element, then you see the href's, and even those will take you off to the [MS Catalog page](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) as a search, that you'd then have to interact with (and if you've neve been to that page, it will force you to accept that one as well). So, this stuff only gets render using the a browser.

So, that means, just getting to the table (excluding all the accepts steps), you'd have something like the below using IE. I am not going to act on that first URL, since you are already dealing with that.

```
# Get all tables on a web page.
$Url1 = 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4000825'
$Url2 = 'https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV990001'

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
while ($ie.Busy) {Sleep 1}

$ie.navigate($Url2)
while ($ie.Busy) {Sleep 1}

$KBTable = ForEach ($table in $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('table')){ $table }
$KBPattern = 'https.*KB\d{7}'
[regex]::Matches(($KBTable | ConvertTo-Xml).Objects.Object.Property.'#text',$KBPattern).Value

# Results
https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4093430
https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4093430
https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB4465659
```

… then of course do as you wish with those links.